# Finding the proper pid to kill -HUP for logrotate

Tags: kill, signals, logrotate

I'm learning about logrotate configs. So I've been reading the man page for commands and looking at  logrotate configs for specific application logs, I see the snipit below often. (Centos 6.8 and below environments)

```
postrotate
   /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/XXX.pid 2>/dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
endscript
```

or something along these lines. My question is if the process I need to `kill -HUP` (which by the way I can't find in `kill --help` or `man kill` or `man signal`) is not in `/var/run/xx.pid` how do I stop the process from still writing to the file ? I know how to kill a process but I just want to stop it from writing the file, or make it re-read the file descriptor, like the example above, or at least I thinks that's what it does.

Comment: HUP signal is kill -1

Comment: Thanks. im still not sure where to find other *.pid items to stop my program from writing to the log for a second or two

Comment: “I came to get help, not to get my question edited.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing what PID to kill is the point of having a pidfile in `/var/run` (or under `/run/user/$UID` for processes that are managed by your own user account). If your process doesn't write such a file, then you should either configure it to do so (if possible) or run it via a [supervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision) that creates a pidfile.

As a last resort, you can check which processes have the log file open with [`fuser`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_(Unix)), or even kill those processes outright (if you do that, don't forget the `-w` option, to only kill processes that are writing to the file), e.g.

```
ps $(fuser /path/to/log/file 2>/dev/null)
fuser -w -k -HUP /path/to/log/file
```

Comment: Looks like I got to learn more about my application. Thanks for the help.